# enquo() inside a magrittr pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, rlang, tidyeval

I just would like to understand what's going wrong here. 
In the first case (working), I assign the `enquo()`-ted argument to a variable, in the second case, I use the enquoted argument directly in my call to `mutate`.

```
library("dplyr")
df <- tibble(x = 1:5, y= 1:5, z = 1:5)

# works
myfun <- function(df, transformation) {
  my_transformation <- rlang::enquo(transformation)
  df %>% 
    gather("key","value", x,y,z) %>% 
    mutate(value = UQ(my_transformation))
}
myfun(df,exp(value))

# does not work
myfun_2 <- function(df, transformation) {
  df %>% 
    gather("key","value", x,y,z) %>% 
    mutate(value = UQ(rlang::enquo(transformation)))
}
myfun_2(df,exp(value))
#>Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `value` is of unsupported type closure
```

**Edit**
Here are some more lines to think about :)

Wrapping the call into quo() it looks as if the expression to evaluate is "built" correctly

```
# looks as if the whole thing should be working
myfun_2_1 <- function(df, transformation) {
  quo(df %>% 
    gather("key","value", x,y,z) %>% 
    mutate(value = UQ(rlang::enquo(transformation))))
}
myfun_2_1(df,exp(value))
```

If you tell this to `eval_tidy`, it works (it doesn't work without quo())

```
# works
myfun_2_2 <- function(df, transformation) {
  eval_tidy(quo(df %>% 
    gather("key","value", x,y,z) %>% 
    mutate(value = UQ(rlang::enquo(transformation)))))
}
myfun_2_2(df,exp(value))
```

If you don't use the pipe, it also works

```
# works
myfun_2_3 <- function(df, transformation) {
  mutate(gather(df,"key","value", x,y,z), value = UQ(rlang::enquo(transformation)))
}
myfun_2_3(df,exp(value))
```

Regarding the error message, this is what one gets, when one tries to pass types that are not supported by data.frames, eg.

mutate(df, value = function(x) x)
   # Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :   Column `value` is of unsupported type closure

To me it looks as if the quosure in myfun_2 isn't evaluated by `mutate`, which is somehow interesting/non-intuitive behaviour. Do you think I should report this to the developers?

Comment: By the way, when looking at the data.frame during the pipe - sequence after "gather()", it says that column "value" is of type integer

Comment: I would rename your question to: Using `enquo()` inside a magrittr pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This limitation is solved in rlang 0.2.0.

Technically: The core of the issue was that magrittr evaluates its arguments in a child of the current environment. This is this environment that contains the `.` pronoun. As of 0.2.0, capture of arguments with `enquo()` and variants is now lexically scoped, which means it looks up the stack of parent environments to find the argument to capture. This solves the magrittr problem.